# Cakephp 2 additional joins for "threaded" query

Tags: cakephp, join, tree, cakephp-2.0

I am using the tree behavior and when I query via **->find('threaded', ...)** - as expected - I get the tree back.

But I want additional joins happen, so something like:

```
$data = $this->Category->find('threaded', array(
    'joins' => array(
        array('table' => 'videos',
            'alias' => 'Video',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Category.id = Video.category_id',
            )
        )
    )
));
```

**Category** hasMany **Video**, but **Video** is not a tree, just related.

Can I use the threaded query for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To produce the "threaded" output Cake 1) calls a find('all), then 2) puts the resulting array through Set::nest() function.

So just get your output using a standard find + your custom joins, then just use the [`Set::nest`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set%3a%3anest)

(NB: `Hash` has replaced `Set` in Cake 2, but Cake still uses `Set` internally. Both will work for now. [`Hash::nest`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash%3a%3anest) )

So if you take a look at Cake's `model.php`, the nest function is called like so:

```
return Set::nest($results, array(
            'idPath' => '/' . $this->alias . '/' . $this->primaryKey,
            'parentPath' => '/' . $this->alias . '/' . $parent
        ));
```

Use that as a template for your call. For your data it would look something like:

```
return Set::nest($results, array(
            'idPath' => '/Category/id',
            'parentPath' => '/Category/parent_id'           ));
```

Comment: Another interesting question is how I can limit this query to one parent node. This is of course nested in application code so I need to query all element because I don't know in advance what the childrens are. Hmm I probably open another question for that or created the query by hand.

Comment: How about: in your original find calls, just set one of the conditions to `'parent_id'  => $your_parent_id` ?

Comment: it's a tree you need also child nodes

Comment: `Set::nest` accepts a "root" parameter to set get a sub-tree. [See the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set::nest)